# PHP Search array for partial or exact match

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which will iterate over an array in PHP and all to search for a value.

```
function checkarrayvalues($term, $arr, $strict = false) {
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $term : $item == $term) || (is_array($item) && checkarrayvalues($term, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I've got it working for complete/exact matches.  But I also need to test for partial matches, which is where I'm now lost.  For instance, if someone searches for "Dall" and "Dallas" exists within the array, it needs to return a positive there as well.

What am I missing in how to do this?

Array looks like:

```
 [Beau Rivage Resort & Casino] => Array
            (
                [name] => Beau Rivage Resort & Casino
                [nid] => 100
                [alias] => /BeauRivage
                [guestrooms] => 1740
                [meetingrooms] => 16
                [largestmr] => 17000
                [totalms] => 50000
                [picture] => /2016-12/Beau-Rivage-Fallen-Oak-Golf-Course_0.jpg
                [region] => SE
                [segment] => GC
                [city] => Biloxi
                [state] => MS
                [longstate] => mississippi
                [address] => 875 Beach Boulevard
                [zip] => 39530
                [country] => United States of America
                [distance] => 21.00
            )

        [Bellagio] => Array
            (
                [name] => Bellagio
                [nid] => 103
                [alias] => /Bellagio
                [guestrooms] => 3933
                [meetingrooms] => 50
                [largestmr] => 45000
                [totalms] => 200000
                [picture] => /2016-12/Bellagio-exterior.jpg
                [region] => SW
                [segment] => BB
                [city] => Las Vegas
                [state] => NV
                [longstate] => nevada
                [address] => 3600 Las Vega Boulevard South
                [zip] => 89109
                [country] => United States of America
                [distance] => 10.00
            )
```

Comment: I would give strpos a try

Comment: typo - in_array_r is supposed to be checkarrayvalues

Comment: Yep - it's recursively going through the array to search for the term.

Comment: Can you post how your array looks like?

Comment: Added an example from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following extended solution with `strpos`, `stripos` and `call_user_func` functions:

```
function checkarrayvalues($term, $arr, $strict = false, $partial = false) {
    if ($partial) {  // whether it should perform a partial match
        $fn = ($strict) ? "strpos" : "stripos";
    }
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            if (checkarrayvalues($term, $item, $strict, $partial))
                return true;
        } elseif (($partial && call_user_func($fn, $item, $term) !== false) 
                || ($strict ? $item === $term : $item == $term)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$arr = [
    ['Dallas', 'New York']
];

var_dump(checkarrayvalues('dall', $arr, true, true));  // false
var_dump(checkarrayvalues('dall', $arr, false, true)); // true
var_dump(checkarrayvalues('york', $arr, false, true)); // true
var_dump(checkarrayvalues('york', $arr, false));       // false
```